# why is my 'com.google.gms.google-services' is invalid (flutter)

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I am trying to run flutter with firebase and i cannot find where i go wrong

plug-ins:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15'
    }
```

Error that keeps on throwing :

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Supplied String module notation 'com.google.gms.google-services' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

i try to comment this line in main.dart :

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

i can run the program but the firebase is not working now

NOTE :
im new into programming and english is not my first language , so im sorry if my spelling is
incorrect , and if i do please correct me

Comment: That line should be `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`